# Bad Decrypt while decrypting data bag using data_bag_item API

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I am using the following key to create encrypted data bag. The key is loaded on the sever node in file `/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret`:

```
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
```

I created the data bag using following command:

```
knife data bag create tokens masterkey --secret-file PATH_TO_SECRET
```

Now, within the recipe, I am using `data_bag_items API` to retrieve value of the data bag item as follows:

```
value = data_bag_item("tokens", "masterkey", "/etc/chef/encrypted_data_bag_secret")

token2_hash = lambda { token1_hash.deep_merge({ "value" => value['key'] } ) }
```

However, I am getting below compile time error:

```
ERROR: Error decrypting data bag value: 'bad decrypt'. Most likely the provided key is incorrect
```

Comment: `--secret-file PATH_TO_SECRET` which path did you use ? are you sure the file you did use there is really the same as on your nodes ?